# Prove EXPTIME \ NP is not a subset of NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, np-hard, np, co-np

If we assume that NP is not equal to co-NP, how do we show that EXPTIME \ NP is not a subset of NP-Hard?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note **co-NP** $\subseteq$ **EXPTIME**, and **co-NP-complete** $\cap$ **NP** = $\emptyset$ since **NP** $\neq$ **co-NP**, it remains to prove **co-NP-complete** $\nsubseteq$ **NP-hard**.

> Further hint: if **co-NP-complete** $\subseteq$ **NP-hard**, try to show for each language $L\in$ **NP**, you can build a NTM deciding $\bar L$, thus **NP** $\subseteq$ **co-NP**, a contradiction.